# combine strings containing NULL

Tags: vba, null, confluence-rest-api

I am attempting to use the [confluence REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest/) to attach files to a wiki page. I generate assorted graphs in excel using VBA and save them as images (currently as png/jpeg).

I then use the [example](https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/) here to upload a file to the wiki as an attachment. This method works well for text files, but when I attempt to use images I run into some issues. Specifically as I understand it the code:

```
sPostData = "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile""; filename=""" & Mid$(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    sPostData & vbCrLf & _
    "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & "--"
```

attempts to add string boundaries to the binary representation of the file by concatenating string. My issue is that the representation for the png contains NUL

```
‰PNG
SUB
NULNULNUL
IHDRNULNULEOT+NULNULSTXSYNBSETXNULNULSOH>&Ç¼      ...etc...
```

which promptly terminates the string, and so you lose the rest of the file and the final string boundary. I believe this occurs with all string functionality in excel.

My question is how should I go about attaching the string boundaries to my file so as to avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: VBA strings are not null terminated meaning they can contain null characters, although these will cause the string to appear truncated in some parts of the debugger.

Comment: Doh! You're completely right, I've misdiagnosed the issue due to this truncation.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex K. pointed out I have been working under an incorrect assumption. The truncation is present in my analysis of the issue and not the actual string.

The problem was actually due to a mistake on my part - from the webiste:

> Another caveat is the pvToByteArray function. It turns out send
>   method can not handle “byref” byte arrays, so for instance passing
>   baBuffer will fail, as VB6 sets up VT_BYREF bit of the type of the
>   variant parameter.

It was my implementation of this part of the code that was incorrect - this caused the failure and the error message

> 500: Stream ended unexpectedly

After correcting this the issue appears resolved.

Thanks again Alex.